# How to create mask file (txt or netcdf) from shapefile using ArcGIS or QGIS?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop

I have a shapefile of el Congo River Basin dy area. Attributes information is just area. Actually I want create a mask with ones in the river basin and ceros outside to just used later in IDL or matlab a mask of the Congo. How can I built a proper mask file (1 inside the congo, o outside) using this shapefile in Arcgis or QGIS ?

I downloaded here: http://hydrosheds.cr.usgs.gov/datadownload.php?reqdata=30bass a shp from the rivers basin of Africa, I selected the congo river basin and I need to convert the whole Africa or just the selected area to a mask of netcdf like a basemap to use later in IDl normally is a matrix of 1 inside the river basin and ceros outside. Thansk !!!!

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to convert your shapefile to a raster format, (adding a new field and setting the value to 1), but txt or NetCDF is not necessary if you then use IDL or Matlab : a tif file (for example) would be fine. IDL reads TIFF directly and you can use imread in Matlab.

In ArcGIS : [Feature to raster](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00120000002v000000)

In QGIS : [Rasterize](http://docs.qgis.org/2.6/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdalogr/gdal_conversion/rasterize.html)

Note that you can then convert to [NetCDF](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_netcdf.html) using gdal_translate (also accessible from QGIS with Raster menu - Conversion - Translate (Convert format)) or [Raster to NetCDF](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//004300000008000000) in ArcGIS. I would not use a txt even if the conversion is possible in ArcGIS ([raster to ascii](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001200000005000000)) and in QGIS, because there are many txt format and I don't know which one to use.

Comment: Thank you !!! but I just need a matrix of 0 and 1 thus I can use it as basemap for a model that runs in IDL but it need to be in .nc or .txt

Comment: you can create the netcdf with gdal_translate as I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: should I first rasterize ?

Comment: yes : first you rasterize and the you convert to netCDF.